# C# : How to find and click an element after refreshing the page

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

On the site there are a group of elements (with class = "listing-price") that appear after more than 10 seconds. I want to click on the specific element that contains the text, "Hello".

My code refreshes the page non-stop and I can see the element, but it doesn't click on it.

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        IList<IWebElement> listingElements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='listing-price']"));
        foreach (IWebElement listingElement in listingElements)
        {
            if (listingElement.Text.Contains("Hello"))
            {
                var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                var element2 = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(listingElement));
                ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element2);
                Debug.WriteLine("I find the element");
                element2.Click();
                return;
            }
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("I dont find the element");
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        driver.Navigate().Refresh();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: _`(By.XPath("//div[@class='listing-price']")`_: It is highly unlikely you would be able to click a `<div>` element unless special circumstances. Update the question with the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I simplified your code a bit.

1. Rather than getting all the elements and then looping through the collection looking for the contained text, "Hello", you can just add that condition to your XPath so that you only locate the right element the first time.
2. I moved the wait for clickable to the initial find to reduce code even further.
3. I changed the caught exception to specifically and only `WebDriverTimeoutException` because it's a bad practice to catch all exceptions. It makes debugging that much harder when things go wrong.
4. I didn't add it but you should add a basic timeout escape from your `while` loop because your current code can easily go into an infinite loop.

Adding all this in, the updated code is below. If this doesn't work, it's likely that your XPath is not correct. I'd fix it for you but you'd need to post the relevant HTML.

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
        var element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[@class='listing-price'][contains(.,'Hello')]")));
        Debug.WriteLine("Found the element");
        ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
        element.Click();

        return;
    }
    catch (WebDriverTimeoutException ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Element not found");
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        driver.Navigate().Refresh();
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```